# python find the optimal # of cluster for K-Means algorithm

Tags: python, scikit-learn, missing-data, k-means, k-nearest-neighbour

I have a data that contains 24 features and all features have some missing values. I want to use the impute-KNN algorithm from sklearn to fill the missing values. However, before I do that, I think I need to find the optimal K (# of clusters) to input into the function. Does anyone know how I can find the optimal K when I have missing values in all features? I am thinking to use K-Means, but K-Means requires all features' values to be integers (non missing).

Comment: FYI [n_neighbors](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.KNNImputer.html) is the $k$ in KNN. There is no K-means involved.

Comment: But for K means, in order to run it, I need to fill in the missing first no? How can deal with the missing before the K mean? cuz I want to use K means to find the optimal K to run KNN imputer, but first I need to deal with the missing in all features.

Comment: The "K" from KNN and K-means are not related in any particular way. (Imagine you have two clusters, both with 4 points. So for K-means you have $k=2$ clusters. But for KNN each point has $k=3$ nearest neighbors within its cluster.) So for your problem, K-means is a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring).